# react tinymce disappears character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I have a react-tinymce project. The functionality I have is this: When the user surrounds word/words inside <> then an api call is made. But the proble is, when the user puts > it flashes and then disappears. The code I'm using is as below.
p.s. I have to use useeffect for api call but trying first to figure out that issue.

```
  function handleOnEditorChange(newValue, editor) {
      const plainText = editor.getContent({ format: "text" });
      setSession({ ...session, sessionText: newValue });
      fetch(`api call`, {
        method: "PATCH",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          uid,
          timestamp: parseInt(timestamp),
          sessionText: newValue,
          plainText: plainText,
          modifiedAt: convertTimestamp(Date.now()).toDateAndHour,
        }),
      })
        .then(function (res) {
          // console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(function (res) {
          console.log(res);
        });
  }

<EditorMce
          apiKey="api key"
          value={session ? session.sessionText : ""}
          onEditorChange={handleOnEditorChange}
          init={{
            init_instance_callback: (editor) => {
              editor.on("keydown", async (event) => {
                if (event.key === "<") {
                  flag = true;
                }
                if (
                  flag &&
                  event.key !== "<" &&
                  event.key !== ">" &&
                  event.key !== "Shift"
                ) {
                  if (event.key === "Backspace") {
                    userQuestion = userQuestion.slice(0, -1);
                  } else {
                    userQuestion += event.key;
                  }
                }
                if (event.key === ">") {
                  flag = false;
//if comment out the setIsWaitAnswer(true) because wont rerender, the > symbol stays but
// i want to be able to update the content tha's why I have that state. I trigger a //useeffect rerun in order to fetch updated content
                  setIsWaitAnswer(true);

                  fetch(`api call`, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                      "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                      uid,
                      timestamp: parseInt(timestamp),
                      question: userQuestion,
                    }),
                  })
                    .then(function (res) {
                      setIsWaitAnswer(false);
                    })
                    .catch(function (res) {});

                  userQuestion = "";
                }
              });
            },
        />
```